# PHP Converting string to timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp

I'm working with a string that represents a timestamp in this format:

```
Mon Jul 13 11:32:00 EST 2015
```

I now need to convert this into a timestamp to insert into my database in this format:

```
MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS
```

I would usually use this:

```
date("m/d/Y h:i:s A", $timestamp)
```

but this isn't working. I don't need to worry about timezones as the timestamp is in the local timezone already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the timestamp string into a time first.  If you want to ignore the timezone, you can do something like:

```
// Set the time
$time = "Mon Jul 13 11:32:00 EST 2015";
// Cut out the timezone details
$time = str_replace(" EST", "", $time);
// Convert the string time into a time and then into a timestamp
$timestamp = date("m/d/Y h:i:s A", strtotime($time));
// echo $timestamp = "07/13/2015 11:32:00 AM"
```

Or, you can use something like mktime() (http://php.net/mktime) but this requires you splitting up your time string into separate elements.

Answer (score 0):

Just two lines of code. Using Datetime object will make your code cleaner.

```
<?php
$datetime = new Datetime("Mon Jul 13 11:32:00 EST 2015");
print $datetime->format("m/d/Y h:i:s A");
```